# How to calculate an arithmetic expression in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have to calculate an arithmetic expression in Assembly? I've tried something but it obviously doesn't work. The expression: (a * b * c + c * d) / d

My work so far:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
a dw ?
b db ?
c dw ?
d dw ?
rez dw ?
m1 db 10, 13, "The result: ", '$'
a1 db 10, 13, "a = ", '$'
b1 db 10, 13, "b = ", '$'
c1 db 10, 13, "c = ", '$'
d1 db 10, 13, "d = ", '$'
.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
```

reading a from keyboard and transforming it into a number

```
; afisare a = si citire a (simbol -> cifra)
mov ah, 9
lea dx, a1
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h

sub al, 30h
mov a, al
```

reading b from keyboard and transforming it into a number

```
; afisare b = si citire b (simbol -> cifra)
mov ah, 9
lea dx, b1
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h

sub al, 30h
mov b, al
```

reading c from keyboard and transforming it into a number

```
; afisare c = si citire c (simbol -> cifra)
mov ah, 9
lea dx, c1
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h

sub al, 30h
mov c, al
```

reading d from keyboard and transforming it into a number

```
; afisare d = si citire d (simbol -> cifra)
mov ah, 9
lea dx, c1
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h

sub al, 30h
mov d, al

mov ax, 0
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 0
mov dx, 0
```

multiplying a with b

```
; a * b
mov al, a
mul b

mov bx, ax
mov ax, 0
```

multiplying the result of the previous operation with c

```
; a * b * c, al = a * b 
mov al, bx
mul c

mov bx, ax
mov ax, 0

mov al, c
mul d
```

I tried to show the result on the screen

```
mov rez, bx

mov ah,9
lea dx, rez
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
end
```

The comments are for my teacher.

EDIT:

I got help for this and this is what I have:

```
mov al, b   ; al = b
cbw         ; ax = b
imul a      ; dx:ax = a * b

imul c      ; dx:ax = a * b * c

mov bx, ax  ; bx a * b * c
mov ax, c   ; ax = c
imul d      ; dx:ax = c * d

add ax, bx  ; ax = a * b * c + c * d
cwd         ; dx:ax = a * b * c + c * d
idiv d
```

Comment: please always tag the correct architecture along with [tag:assembly]

Comment: `mov al, bx` <-- How did you even manage to assemble that? `al` is an 8-bit register but `bx` is a 16-bit register.

Comment: In any case, there's no interrupt function that will print an integer for you. So you'll have to convert your integer result into a string yourself, and then print the string.

Comment: Side note: `a1`, `b1`, etc aren't very good label names, since 1) they look kind of similar to `al`, `bl`, etc, and 2) they're pretty non-descriptive (what is a _b1_?).

Comment: I fixed all the issues you pointed out (I had them cause I'm crap at assembly), thanks. I have new ones though :D.